# iLO default username always Administrator?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I have noticed that all the HP ProLiant I have access, have the same iLO default username : Administrator.

Is it always the same default username ? Some kind of HP internal rule ...

(I want to do some scripting around this, I would like to confirm that it is a constant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default is burned in per server (id is always `Administrator`, but the password is different).

You can press `F8` during `POST` to enter the ILO configuration screen and reset it there.

Comment: Is there some physical place on server, where I can find the password?

Comment: There may be a sticker label or a device tag attached to the server with that password and serial number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Always `Administrator`. If you're scripting, be sure to use the `hponcfg` utility. (don't reinvent the wheel)